# How to accept connections from local network only in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a ServerSocket object that is listening with accept method.  How do I accept connections only coming from the same network and not outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system has multiple network interfaces and one of them is receiving local connections only while others should be ignored, you can set up a `ServerSocket` with the IP-address of the netork interface to bind it only to that particular interface:

```
ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(1234, 10, InetAddress.getByAddress("192.168.1.1"));
```

With IPv4 and IPv6 you obviously need two ServerSockets.

If local and remote connections are received from the same network interface, you have to check the remote peer yourself. This can be done in different ways:

- You can set a `SecurityManager` that implements `checkAccept` and throws a `SecurityException` if the connection attempts comes from the wrong place. This is a global setting, so with this you can't set up a `ServerSocket` at some other part of the application that should accept connections from there.
- You can check the IP and port of the `Socket` being returned from `ServerSocket` to be local and close the socket if it's not instead of continuing with the request
- You can create a subclass of `ServerSocket` overriding the method [`checkAccept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) where call `super.accept`, do the corresponding check as described in option 2 and only return the retrieved connection if it fit to your criterias or otherwise close it and call the super-method again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found an easier way I think. isAnyLocalAddress() is returning true if the connection is coming from local network.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `ServerSocket` via the constructor that accepts a local IP address, and supply `127.0.0.1` as that IP address.

Comment: As far as I understood the question, it's about connections from local systems, i.e. systems in the same network as the local machine. So we're not talking about connections from `localhost`